# Rails 3 Mechanize - SocketError: getaddrinfo: Host or name not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mechanize

I am using mechanize and i get this error. Can someone please help me.

I have set meta refresh to true.

Error log:

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Host or name not known
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in 'initiallize'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in 'open'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in 'block in connect'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in 'timeout'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in 'timeout'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in 'connect'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in 'do_start'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:632:in 'start'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.0/lib/mechanize.rb:527:in 'fetch_page'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.0/lib/mechanize.rb:591:in 'fetch_page'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.0/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in 'post_form'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.0/lib/mechanize.rb:370:in 'submit'
    form C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.0/lib/form.rb:141:in 'submit'
```

Updated - Error message on form submit
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuo9u.png

Form
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlrIm.png

Comment: getaddrinfo is a C network call. It looks like your app is trying to connect somewhere but it fails to get the ip. I've seen similar errors when I'm not connected to any networks. Can you paste the html form that mechanize sees?

Comment: I am conntected to a network. It only displays the error message when follow_meta_refresh is set to true. I have posted the form and a new error message.

Comment: and can you connect form the console to the host name in the form.action? try `telnet www.yourhost.com 80` to check if you can actually connect. And please put text, not images

Comment: I cannot use telnet in cmd console or ruby console (NameError).

Comment: I have installed telnet now on my windows 7 mashine. But i stil get the socketerror. I can now connect via telnet to www.yourhost.com

Answer (score 0):

Create **config/initializers/requires.rb**
with **require 'resolv-replace'**
inside

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add more details to your answer, as one-sentence answers not best suited for SO. For more details, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.