# How to manipulate a URL in Rails/Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to manipulate a URL to get just the base site name.

For example I have the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask,
```

which should just return `stackoverflow`.

Also if I have  the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988199/rails-3-mechanize-socketerror-getaddrinfo-host-or-name-not-known
```

it should also be only `stackoverflow`.

Final example, if I have the URL:

```
http://www.google.dk/search?q=ruby+string+manipulation
```

it should be `google`.

How do I strip away everything but the domain name of a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to use the [Domainatrix](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix) gem to take care of this for you. Once you have it installed, it's just a matter of doing this:

```
url = Domainatrix.parse("http://www.google.dk/search?q=ruby+string+manipulation")
url.domain # returns 'google'
```

There are a few more code examples and options on their github page.

Answer (score 9):

You could use something already available in the std Ruby distribution:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "uri"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> a = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x3b3eb78 URL:http://www.google.com>
irb(main):003:0> a.host
=> "www.google.com"
irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a separate gem, you can try some simple regex

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^\.]+).*
```